# How to best hint at rustc that a recursive data-structure based on Pointee::Metadata is well-formed?

Tags: rust

The Rust compiler [chokes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=412b38d05d47e8d5c9662038d8d43ef3) on the following code:

```rust
#![feature(ptr_metadata)]

use core::ptr::Pointee;

struct TypedHandle<E: ?Sized, H> {
    handle: H,
    metadata: <E as Pointee>::Metadata,
}

type NodeHandle<T, H> = TypedHandle<Node<T, H>, H>;

struct Node<T, H> {
    element: T,
    next: NodeHandle<T, H>,
    prev: NodeHandle<T, H>,
}
```

There seems to be a type inference/type resolution issue, however the notes are all over the place with weirdly seemingly unrelated suggestions:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:14:11
   |
14 |     next: NodeHandle<T, H>,
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `<Node<T, H> as Pointee>::Metadata == _`
note: required because it appears within the type `TypedHandle<Node<T, H>, H>`
  --> src/lib.rs:5:8
   |
5  | struct TypedHandle<E: ?Sized, H> {
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type
   = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
   |
14 |     next: &NodeHandle<T, H>,
   |           +
help: the `Box` type always has a statically known size and allocates its contents in the heap
   |
14 |     next: Box<NodeHandle<T, H>>,
   |           ++++                +
```

Various changes to the code "solve" the error (but break functionality):

- Using `NonNull<E>` instead of `<E as Pointee>::Metadata`. This suggests that the recursive nature of the type is not the sole issue.
- Removing the `?Sized` bound on `E` in `TypedHandle`.
- Removing one of `next` or `prev`. This suggests that the note about `next` not being able to be both unsized and non-last field is actually "serious", despite the fact that `TypedHandle` is always sized.

Various changes to the code that do not help:

- Switching `NodeHandle` from type alias to tuple struct. It doesn't help with the error message either.

The only solution I found so far is adding `where NodeHandle<T, H>: Sized` bound to `Node`, which is *quite* unwieldy as this bound has to be replicated *everywhere* afterwards.

- Is this a known limitation of the compiler?
- Is there a better way to solve the problem?

*Note: the problem appeared in [a custom implementation of `LinkedList`](https://github.com/matthieu-m/storage/blob/b4235a8b17c488abb9093721c15dc951f441191d/src/collection/linked_list.rs) as I explore a new allocation API, I worked around it by copy/pasting `TypedHandle` into `SizedHandle` and removing the `?Sized` bound on `E`, which leaves an ugly taste in my mouth, but is easier to fix back than copy/pasted bounds all over the place.*

Comment: [You don't need `H` to trigger the error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=207e40e3a100f3ef9187793b8cec294f).

Comment: [And even more minimal example, without `TypedHandle`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46f4fd1a8a0ee418ba8cdf65cfa155a3).

Comment: I'd say report a bug.

Comment: [Issue submitted to rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/111821), to hopefully fix the type inference/resolution so that no work-around is necessary in the first place.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Doh! `H` was so essential to the original code this was extracted from that I never considered removing it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Your second reduction interestingly fails to mention the sizedness issue, so it's more minimal, but it's not clear whether it's exactly the same issue. (I do suspect it is). I added a variant of it to the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nightly regression, which @lukas-code identified in [this github comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/111821#issuecomment-1556233712) on the I issue raised.

In the very same comment, he also suggests a much more lightweight work-around: adding a `_tail: ()` field to make the compiler realize a type is sized.

In particular, the `TypedHandle` definition can be changed to:

```rust
struct TypedHandle<E: ?Sized, H> {
    handle: H,
    metadata: <E as Pointee>::Metadata,
    _self_is_always_sized: (),
}
```

So that the work-around is as scoped as possible.

Comment: Putting `handle` (or `element` from the question) last also fixes that. That seems to be better than adding a otherwise useless unit to the struct.

Comment: @cafce25: Maybe. The one advantage of the "useless" field is that it can have a name that describes its purpose, and I'd add a comment linking to the bug report too. But in the end indeed all that matters is having a sized field at the end.